# How to map id with name to form a new table in pypmyadmin - MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I have a table named "item" as shown below:

```
itemId  itemName
001     Chicken Chop
002     Mushroom Chicken
003     Grilled Chicken
004     Chicken Maryland
```

Then, I have a table named "genRecom" as shown below:

```
id     orderItem1   recomItem1
359    001          002
360    001,003      002
361    001          002,003
362    001          003
363    001,002      003
```

From both of the tables above, I want my table "Recom" to be as follows:

```
id     orderItem1                      recomItem1
359    Chicken Chop                    Mushroom Chicken
360    Chicken Chop, Grilled Chicken   Mushroom Chicken
361    Chicken Chop                    Mushroom Chicken, Grilled Chicken
362    Chicken Chop                    Grilled Chicken
363    Chicken Chop, Mushroom Chicken  Grilled Chicken
```

Does anyone know how should I combine both codes to produce a table "Recom" looks like the one I mentioned above? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? It often does make a difference whether you're using MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL Server or IBM DB2 - or something else even. Please add a relevant tag to your question!

Comment: @marc_s I'm using MySQL, the DB used is phpmyadmin. I have editted my question. If you know how to do this, please kindly teach me. Thank you!

Comment: @GurV Normalization can help to solve this? May I know how? Since there is also a comma separator between some items..

Answer (score 0):

You should not store delimited values. You should normalize the data. Meaning one value in one cell.

You can use the below query for now using `find_in_set`:

```
select
    g.id,
    group_concat(i1.itemName order by i1.itemId) as orderItem1,
    group_concat(i2.itemName order by i2.itemId) as recomItem1
from genRecom g
join item i1 on find_in_set(i1.itemId, g.orderItem1) > 0
join item i2 on find_in_set(i2.itemId, g.recomItem1) > 0
group by g.id;
```

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/XBUG25908)

As per currently stored data, this will work only if the itemId column in Item table is of varchar type with exact same number of zeros in them.

Note that above query is not Sargable which means it can't use indexes and thus can be lead to performance issues.

If you had stored the data a bit differently in your genRecom table (type of the two columns can be int. Similarly type of itemId in item table can be int):

```
id    orderItem1   recomItem1
01    001          002
02    001          002
02    003          002
03    001          002
03    001          003
04    001          003
```

Then, it was a simple join:

```
select
    g.id,
    group_concat(i1.itemName order by i1.itemId) as orderItem1,
    group_concat(i2.itemName order by i2.itemId) as recomItem1
from genRecom g
join item i1 on i1.itemId = g.orderItem1
join item i2 on i2.itemId = g.recomItem1
group by g.id;
```

Which would perform much better and is Sargable.

#### [Demo](http://rextester.com/SFK48166)

EDIT:

The above queries produced your expected output. If you don't want to get the comma separated output, just use join alone:

```
select
    g.id,
    i1.itemName as orderItem1,
    i2.itemName as recomItem1
from genRecom g
join item i1 on i1.itemId = g.orderItem1
join item i2 on i2.itemId = g.recomItem1;
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. If I do it this way, then in the table "recom", for id 2, recomItem1 will show "Mushroom Chicken,Mushroom Chicken" instead of "Mushroom Chicken". Any solution for this if I wish to show "Mushroom Chicken" only?

Comment: @K.W - That was to meet your expected result. I've updated the answer. Please see the last one.

Comment: I'm still have a look on the code :) By the way, thanks for ur help!

Comment: May I know what does this line of code "join item i1 on find_in_set(i1.itemId, g.orderItem1) > 0" means? Why is > 0? When I apply the first stack of code from your answer (the one with find_in_set) in my program, I get a result of [].

Comment: @K.W - It find the first parameter passed to it in comma separated value of the second parameters. `> 0` means it exists in the second string. Is the datatype of itemId column in item table numeric? If so, you'll have to format it to have exact same number of zeros as in second table. This is exactly why you should normalize your table.